# A way by which a number can be passed to the overridden function onRequestPermissionsResult?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I am trying to make a code asking for permissions and making a phone call. The number is entered by the user and is taken by an editText. I can't find a way to do so because the overridden function onRequestPermissionsResult also calls the function makePhoneCall()

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar

const val PERMISSION_REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 0

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val callSupport = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        val enterNumber = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.enterPhone)
        val number = enterNumber.text.toString()
        callSupport.setOnClickListener {
            makePhoneCallAfterPermission(it,number)
        }
    }
    private fun makePhoneCall(number:String){
        val intent = Intent().apply{
            action = Intent.ACTION_CALL
            data = Uri.parse("tel: $number")
        }
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    private fun makePhoneCallAfterPermission(view: View, number: String){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            makePhoneCall(number)
        }
        else{
            requestCallPermission(view,number)
        }
    }

    private fun requestCallPermission(view: View, number: String){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)){
            val snack = Snackbar.make(view, "The app requires your permission to make phone call .", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            snack.setAction("OK", View.OnClickListener {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE), PERMISSION_REQUEST_PHONE_CALL)
            })
            snack.show()
        }
        else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE), PERMISSION_REQUEST_PHONE_CALL)
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_PHONE_CALL){
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                makePhoneCall()
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied to make a phone call .",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Any help on how I can achieve the result will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change an function from super class because is the super class that call the function, not you. But you can solve this problem by adding a class field so you can access this field by all the non-static methods in the class.